# ModelForm User Mixin

Tags: django, forms, modelform

I've got some models with **user** field.

For this purpose I'd like to create a form mixin that would add `self.user` instance (which is provided to the form in views). Is it possible ?

Here's the example

```
class UserFormMixin(object):
    """Removes user instance from kwargs and adding it to object"""
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UserFormMixin, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.user = kwargs.pop('user')

    def save(self, **kwargs):
        obj = super(UserFormMixin, self).save(commit=False)
        obj.user = self.user
        if kwargs['commit']:
            return obj.save()
        else:
            return obj
```

What I'd like to achieve:

```
class SomeFormWithUserField(UserFormMixin, ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = SomeModelWithUserField
        fields = ['fields without user']

    def save(self, **kwargs):
        data = super(SomeFormWithUserField, sefl).save(commit=False)
        #data already with user prepended
        #do some other stuff with data
        if kwargs['commit']:
            return data.save()
        else
            return data

class SomeOtherFormWithUser(UserFormMixin, ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = SomeOtherModel
        fields = ['some fields without user']

# no need to save here.. standard model form with user prepended on save()
```

The problem is that UserFormMixin doesn't know about model instance? Or am I wrong here?
I am getting some problems.. like 'commit' kwargs key error.. or object is not saved..

Answer (score 6):

You're close, you just have some logic errors. First, in order to override `ModelForm` methods, your mixin needs to inherit from `ModelForm`.

```
class UserFormMixin(forms.ModelForm):
    ...
```

Then, any forms that inherit from it just inherit `UserFormMixin`, not `ModelForm`.

```
class SomeOtherFormWithUser(UserFormMixin):
    ...
```

Second, your `__init__` method override is incorrect. You need to accept any and all args and kwargs that get passed into it.

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    ...
```

Finally, don't override the `save` method again, in the subclass. I guess it won't technically hurt anything, but what's the point of inheritance if you're going to repeat code, anyways? If `user` is not nullable, you can always add an if block to check if `self.user is not None` before adding it to the model. Of course, if `user` is not nullable, your model won't likely save without `self.user` anyways.

Comment: I think UserFormMixin must subclass `forms.Form` and not `forms.ModelForm`, since the latter will require a `model` in its `class Meta`. Also just subclassing UserFormMixin, I think it doesn't make it a Mixin, correct? Mixins are supposed to be supplementary, i.e. they accompany other concrete classes.

Comment: Sorry Chris Pratt, you're correct and the above comment I made is delirious. Please ignore it.

Comment: I think Chris's solution will work (partially). I don't need to specify model in the UserFormMixin class.. but it won't save the form It still doesn't see the object. `obj = super(UserFormMixin, self).save(commit=False)` returns `None`. (As for `__init__`: Yes Chris, this was my mistake, I will edit my post now).

Comment: You don't have  to specify the `Meta` class as long as you don't actually *use* the mixin on it's own. Besides, the `Meta` class is not inherited by default anyways. And, yes, in the strictest sense it's still a mixin: it's a class that adds to another class, and is never used directly. In short, it's a mixin the same way an abstract model is a mixin.

Comment: @Chris: That's why I think the save() will not work (or maybe I'm doing this wrong).

Comment: It would be helpful to see all the code as you have it now. Copy and paste, don't just update the existing code, because it's possible you made a mistake somewhere that you wouldn't make again the second time.

Comment: @rantanplan You are not delirious; this code works but it is *not* an example of a Mixin; you are right that mixins are supplementary. This is an example of *subclassing* and as such using the name Mixin for the class is incorrect.

Comment: @JordanReiter Yeah I had completely forgotten about this comment. It's true, that by definition, mixins should only add functionality and not be instantiatable(or make sense to instantiate them) by themselves.

Answer (score 1):

This one seems to work fine. Thanks Chris!
If this can be coded better please let me know.

```
class UserFormMixin(forms.ModelForm):
    """Removes user instance from kwargs and adding it to object"""
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UserFormMixin, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.user = kwargs.pop('user')

    def save(self, commit=True):
        obj = super(UserFormMixin, self).save(commit=False)
        obj.user = self.user
        if commit:
            return obj.save()
        else:
            return obj


class SomeFormWithUserField(UserFormMixin):
    class Meta:
        model = SomeModelWithUserField
        fields = ['fields without user']

    def save(self, **kwargs):
        data = super(SomeFormWithUserField, sefl).save(commit=False)
        #data already with user prepended
        #do some other stuff with data
        # self.send_mail() f.e.
        return data.save()

class SomeOtherFormWithUser(UserFormMixin):
    class Meta:
        model = SomeOtherModel
        fields = ['some fields without user']
# this will work too
```